# Как сделать вывод только главных категориях OpenCart?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.0

Добрый день. Есть вывод категории. Есть категории первого и второго уровня. Выводиться их названия в сайдбаре. При нажатии на категорию открывается такое же окно( другое содержание) с сайдбаром которые имеет и категории второго уровня. Мне надо что бы всегда и везде были ВСЕ категории только первого уровня. Не пойму в чем ошибка в коде

```
<div class="b-aside-menu">
  <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
  <?php if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
  <ul><li>
  <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
  </li></ul>
  <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
  <?php foreach ($category['children'] as $child) { ?>
  <?php if ($child['category_id'] == $child_id) { ?>
 <ul><li> <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a></li></ul>
  <?php } else { ?>
 <ul><li> <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a></li></ul>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php } else { ?>
 <ul><li> <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li></ul>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Закомментируйте `if ($category['children'])`  и надо немного отредактировать вывод списка:

```
<div class="b-aside-menu">
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
        <ul>
            <?php if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
                <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li>     
<!--
            <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
                <?php foreach ($category['children'] as $child) { ?>
                    <?php if ($child['category_id'] == $child_id) { ?>
                        <ul>
                            <li> <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <ul>
                            <li> <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
-->
            <?php } else { ?>
                <li> <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li> 
            <?php } ?>
        </ul> 
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```